# Remove given characters from a string (D language)

Tags: string, replace, d

I have a string `source` and a string `toBeRemoved`.

I want to remove from `source` all chars which are present in `toBeRemoved`.

What is the best way to do it in D programming language?

**Example**:

```
string source = "abcd";
string toBeRemoved = "bd";
string result = ...; // "ac"
```

Comment: @grooveplex iI didn't try. I can easily write a relatively complex algorithm. The question is for a simple algorithm, which I am probably not ready implement anyway

Comment: Probably using a regex expression?

Comment: @adalPaRi I would need to construct a regex from the `toBeRemoved` string. It is a little non-trivial task

Comment: Could you give an example of source, toBeRemoved, and the desired result.

Comment: @LupusOssorum done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the to be removed characters in advance, you can use `any` as it's a bit faster because it can build a specialized switch table at compile-time:

```
source.filter!(c => !c.any('b', 'd'))
```

Otherwise, e.g. `canFind` helps:

```
source.filter(c => !toBeRemoved.canFind(c))
```

Note that `filter` is lazy (and without allocations). If you really need a string at the end, use e.g. `.to!string`.